# Could not create message: First Element must contain the local name, Envelope , but found Import

Tags: xml, http, soap, xsd, soap-client

I never worked with SOAP requests before and I need to have an integration with a SOAP based interface. In the documentation they posted a sample to their XML objecas follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Import xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Category Name="Bewerbungen/Personen-Import">
        <Record>
            <Field FieldName="Bewerber.Email">
                <String>Wert</String>
            </Field>
            <Field FieldName="Bewerbung.Status">
                <String>2010</String>
            </Field>
            <Field FieldName="Bewerber.Vorname">
                <String>Wert</String>
            </Field>
            <Field FieldName="Bewerber.Name">
                <String>Wert</String>
            </Field>
            <Field FieldName="Bewerber.Telefon">
                <String>Wert</String>
            </Field>
            <Field FieldName="Bewerber.PLZ">
                <String>00000</String>
            </Field>
            <Field FieldName="Stelle.ID">
                <String>Wert</String>
            </Field>
            <Field FieldName="Stelle.Nummer">
                <String>Wert</String>
            </Field>
            <Field FieldName="Bewerber.WieAufmerksamGeworden">
                <String>20003075</String>
            </Field>
            <Field FieldName="Bewerbung.AnmerkungenZurBewerbung">
                <String>Wert</String>
            </Field>
        </Record>
    </Category>
</Import>
```

however I am getting the following error: *{"message":"Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.ws.soap.axiom.AxiomSoapMessageCreationException: Could not create message: First Element must contain the local name, Envelope , but found Import; nested exception is org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAPProcessingException: First Element must contain the local name, Envelope , but found Import","error_id":"11ef3911-9dd1-4072-bd4c-321e975451a3"}*

Also I have to add some fields as per the documentation below but i'm not sure where exactly should i add them before or after the import?

```
 ApplicationUrl: {your application’s address}/Public/Import/HTTPInterface<ApplicationUri>
 AuthenticationKey (string): The authentication key configured in the solution under Settings for automatic imports: <AuthenticationKey>
 ImportType (string): type of file to be imported (available import types are listed below): <ImportType>
 ImportFile (byte array) — binary file content as a byte array <File> (according to the following example structure: XML import/export structure)
 Filename (string): name of the file to be imported (displayed in the solution): <Filename>
```

Comment: The XML file you present is not a SOAP message. A SOAP message always has a <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=".." > root element. Maybe the protocol/API you should use is not SOAP. Maybe this is an example of a <soap:Body> content. However, only the provider of this API can answer these questions.

Comment: What programming language?

Comment: @forty-two thanks for your input, actually you were right and i found a WSDL in the documentation that has in one of its tag options a file tag to include this file content in base64Binary format